# repeat rows based on multiplication of field value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, repeat

I'm trying to produce multiple rows based on a value in a column of my table. I need the number of rows to be three times the value of the data in the column. Currently I have it so it repeats the number of rows based on the value in the column, but I cant work out how to get it procude three times the value in the column. 
Here is my code:

```
WITH tmp as (SELECT 1 as rn UNION ALL SELECT rn+1 from tmp WHERE rn<=1000)

    SELECT 
    [SURNAME],
    [NAME],
    [AGE],
    [PAYMENT DAYS PER/WK]

    FROM 
    [PublishedReporting].[dbo].[Sheet1$]
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM tmp WHERE rn<=50) as 
                                    rowgen on [PAYMENT DAYS PER/WK] >= rowgen.rn

    WHERE
    [PAYMENT DAYS PER/WK] IS NOT NULL

    ORDER BY
    SURNAME,
    NAME

    option (maxrecursion 32767);
```

Here is a sample of my results:
So here it shows 3 rows for Lucy Adams, but I need it to show 9
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from  [PublishedReporting].[dbo].[Sheet1$]  
union all
select * from  [PublishedReporting].[dbo].[Sheet1$]  
union all
select * from  [PublishedReporting].[dbo].[Sheet1$]
order by 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but that produces the same results as my query

Answer (score 0):

As a note, there is an alternative method which generally doesn't require scanning the table three times:

```
select t.*
from  [PublishedReporting].[dbo].[Sheet1$] t cross join
      (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3) rows3
```